# How to test the then part after promise in jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm working on a React project and I'm using jest to write tests for my code.

This is the code I want to test.

```
const handleSubmit = (handleSuccess, handleErrors) => {
  signupAPI(user)
    .then(handleSuccess)
    .catch(handleErrors);
};
```

Here's the test code:

```
test('should call handleSuccess', () => {
  signupAPI.mockImplementation((user) => Promise.resolve(user));
  const handleSuccess = jest.fn();
  const handleErrors = jest.fn();

  handleSubmit(handleSuccess, handleErrors); 

  expect(signupAPI).toHaveBeenCalled(); // test passes

  expect(handleSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled(); // test fails
});
```

When I run the test, it never moves to the 'then' part after the promise. How do I test that the function inside the then part is actually called?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you don't wait for the promise that you create in the test:

```
test('should call handleSuccess', async() => {
  const p = Promise.resolve()
  signupAPI.mockImplementation((user) => p.then(user));
  const handleSuccess = jest.fn();
  const handleErrors = jest.fn();

  handleSubmit(handleSuccess, handleErrors); 
  await p
  expect(signupAPI).toHaveBeenCalled(); // test passes

  expect(handleSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled(); // test fails
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a return in `handleSubmit` it will work. Try this:

```
const handleSubmit = (handleSuccess, handleErrors) => {
  return signupAPI(user)
    .then(handleSuccess)
    .catch(handleErrors);
};
```

And for the test:

```
test('should call handleSuccess', () => {
  signupAPI.mockImplementation((user) => Promise.resolve(user));
  const handleSuccess = jest.fn();
  const handleErrors = jest.fn();

  handleSubmit(handleSuccess, handleErrors).then(() => {
    expect(signupAPI).toHaveBeenCalled(); // test passes

    expect(handleSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled(); // test fails
  });
});
```

It should work just fine! if it does not work you can try to add a return to `handleSubmit` on your test like

```
return handleSubmit(handleSuccess, handleErrors).then(() => {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `handleSubmit` is that it treats promises as glorified callbacks. There's no need to pass callbacks to `then` and `catch`. It doesn't return a promise, so can't be chained.

This is how it could be fixed:

```
const handleSubmit = (handleSuccess, handleErrors) => {
  return signupAPI(user)
    .then(handleSuccess)
    .catch(handleErrors);
};
```

and

```
test('should call handleSuccess', async () => {
  ...
  handleSubmit(handleSuccess, handleErrors); 

  await handleSubmit(handleSuccess, handleErrors); 
  expect(signupAPI).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(handleSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And this is how it could be properly written:

```
const handleSubmit = () => signupAPI(user)
```

Comment: This solution did not always work for me on some particular cases